# Sorting fetched data in controller

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm having a hard time sorting my data. Because I am fetching my data using 2 columns. Is there a way where I can sort it in the controller, ajax, model? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

[image]

**As we can see here, I am fetching all data of test 1. But when I'm fetching it, it is not in ascending order.**

My DB:

[image]

**View:**

```
<div id="testdisplay"></div>
```

**Ajax**

```
<script>

testfetching();
function testfetching(){

var eventID = $('#eventID').val();

  $.ajax({
        url:"<?=site_url('testing/fetching')?>",
        method:"POST",
        data:{eventID:eventID},
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data){
                
        $('#testdisplay').html(data);
    
            
        
        },
    })

}
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
    // is there a way where i can sort my data here in controller?
    // I have tried sorting it using sort($data); but it is not working. 


         function fetching(){
        $entry= $this->matchings->entryfetch();
        
        
        $data = '';
        $data='

    <div class="card table-hover table-responsive" style="display: flex;">
    <table class="mt-3 ml-2" style="">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th style="float: left;">NO.</th>
    <th style="float: left;">ENTRY NAME</th>



    </tr></thead>';
        
        
        foreach($entry as $entry){
            
            $match= $this->matchings->matchfetch($entry->handlerID);
            
            $data.='<thead>
            <tr>
            <th style="float: left; page-break-after: always;"><hr style="">'.$entry->handlerID.'&nbsp;'.$entry->entryName.'</th><th>&nbsp;</th>  ';
            
            
            
            foreach($match as $match){
                

                
                if($match->handlerIDM === $entry->handlerID){
                    $name=$match->handlertestW;
                    $count=$match->cockNoM;
                }else{
                    
                    $name=$match->handlerM;
                    $count=$match->cockNoW;
                }
                
                
    
                
                
                if($match->handlerM === $entry->entryName){
                    $data.='<tbody>
<tr><td style="float: right; margin-right: 5px;">'.$count.'</td>
    


';
                    
                }else{
                    
                    $data.='<tbody><tr> <td style="float: right; margin-right: 5px;">'.$count.'</td>
                        
                       


';
                    
                }
                
                
                
                
                $data.='<td></td></tr></tbody>';
                //
            }
            
            
        }
        
        $data .='</table></div>';

        echo json_encode($data);
 
     
    }
```

**Model:**

```
 function entryfetch(){
        $eventID = $this->input->post('eventID');
        
        $this->db->where('eventID', $eventID);
        $this->db->group_by('handlerID');
        $this->db->order_by('handlerID');
        $query = $this->db->get('entry_test');
        
        return $query->result();
        
        
    }
    
    function matchfetch($entryid){
        
        $eventID = $this->input->post('eventID');
        
        $this->db->where('eventID', $eventID);
        $this->db->where('handlerIDM', $entryid);

      
      
        
        $this->db->or_where('handlerIDW', $entryid);
        $this->db->where('eventID', $eventID);
      
       
    
        $query = $this->db->get('matching');
        
        return $query->result();
        
        
    }
```

Comment: The database table columns at the start of your post do not seem to match any of the queries in your model, so it's not clear what you're currently doing or what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, i have updated it now. Thank you.

Comment: @Ulquiorra Schiffer hello please show us your data using 2 columns.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/-PaYyxos0hfR 
cockNoM and cockNoW.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/CmxU2ot65yNR this is my report

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to order data that's in two columns of the same table you need to use a UNION.

I'm going with just the columns you've provided at the top of your post and the ones in your queries, hopefully this'll help you get started.

Model:

```
function matchfetch($entryid){
    $eventID = $this->input->post('eventID');

    return $this->db->query(
        'SELECT handlerM AS handler, cockNoM AS cockNo
        FROM matching
        WHERE eventID = ? AND handlerIDM = ?

        UNION

        SELECT handlertestW AS handler, cockNoW AS cockNo
        FROM matching
        WHERE eventID = ? AND handlerIDW = ?

        ORDER BY cockNo', [
        $eventID, $entryID, $eventID, $entryID
    ])->result();
}
```

Each SELECT query creates a table (one for handlerM+cockNoM and one for handlertestW+cockNoW) and the UNION stacks them:

[image]

You can then use ORDER BY to order the resulting table.

`handlerM`/`handlertestW` are renamed to `handler` and `cockNoM`/`cockNoW` are renamed to `cockNo` in the resultset, so you'll need to update your controller as well:

Controller:

```
foreach($match as $match){
    $name=$match->handler;
    $count=$match->cockNo;

    $data.='<tbody><tr><td style="float: right; margin-right: 5px;">'.$count.'</td>';
    $data.='<td></td></tr></tbody>';
}
```

If you need extra columns in your result set, add them to both SELECT queries.

Answer (score 0):

I did not see any order type in your query. i.e ASC, DESC

```
$this->db->order_by('handlerID', 'ASC');
```

Comment: I already did. https://prnt.sc/Yje-mVnMd6_f

Comment: $this->db->order_by('handlerID');

Where is second parameter ????

The second parameter lets you set the direction of the result. Options are ASC, DESC AND RANDOM.

Source: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#ordering-results

Comment: Thank you for that, but it is not working. https://prnt.sc/nOxSGKKmcj7P 

Is there a way where I can sort it on the controller?

Comment: Please share your actual table screen shot. I've doubt with using group by and order by on same column

Comment: Thank you for replying. Here it is: https://prnt.sc/LNb_vaF7gZAF  

I need to do it on this column first, once I have applied it to one. I will have the idea to apply it to every column. I hope you can help me ty

Comment: These data are from cockNoM and cockNoW from my Database. https://prnt.sc/UB7THM-nFxJB

Comment: I am still not getting clear picture. Why dont you screen shot your actual mysql table ? or give me direct insert query with dummy data to test.

Comment: prnt.sc/-PaYyxos0hfR cockNoM and cockNoW. These are all my testing data. I am trying to fetch it side by side with ascending order. As we can see on the cockNoM and cockNoW.  https://prnt.sc/CmxU2ot65yNR

Comment: As per screenshots of table provided in your question. Try removing groupby clause.

Comment: This is what happens when i removed it. https://prnt.sc/EmafTRsaE-Zr